# Error Mapping con Spring Boot y Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

Tratando de crear un aplicacion Rest, pero al momento de realizar la consulta no me busca la direccion que tengo en mi maquina

```
package com.mongo.controlador;

import com.mongo.entidades.usuario;
import com.mongo.repositorio.repositoriousuario;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("usuario")

public class controladorusuario {
@Autowired
repositoriousuario user;

@RequestMapping(
value = "/all",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = "application/json"
)
public List<usuario> getall(){
        return user.findAll();
}
}
```

Me muestra el siguiente problema

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Sep 14 15:56:52 CST 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

en la direccion

```
http://localhost:5001/usuario/all
```

el archivo de configuraciones es el siguiente

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=ipbasededatos
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.username=root
spring.data.mongodb.password=root
spring.data.mongodb.database=admin
server.port=5001
```

la entidad creada es la siguiente

```
package com.mongo.entidades;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "usuarios")
public class usuario {
    @Id
    private String Id;
    private String Nombre;

GETTER AND SETTERS
}
```

el repositorio creado es el siguiente

```
package com.mongo.repositorio;

import com.mongo.entidades.usuario;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface repositoriousuario extends MongoRepository<usuario, String>{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con poner "/usuario" en el  tu @RequestMapping del  Rest controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/usuario")   
public class controladorusuario {
@Autowired
repositoriousuario user;

@RequestMapping(
value = "/all",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = "application/json"
)
public List<usuario> getall(){
        return user.findAll();
}
}
```

Saludos

Comment: estimado un gusto te comento que ya realice lo que me indicas pero no tuve exito al realizarlo

Comment: podes mostrar el codigo fuente de la aplicacion principal que levanta Spring boot, el controlador esta dentro del mismo package?

Comment: pone logging.level.org=DEBUG en tu applicaction.properties para ver el log mas detallado de cuando inicia tu aplicacion , para ver si esta mapeando realmente el controlador